# python 2.7 UnicodeDecodeError pyserial

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, decode, pyserial

I'm trying to get pySIMreader from here http://ladyada.net/make/simreader/download.html working with python 2.7 I keep getting this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pySimReader.py", line 267, in buttonConnectReader
    self.SIM.connectReader()
  File "/home/john/Plocha/pySimReader-Serial-src-v2/pySIMserial.py", line 113, in connectReader
    res = self.openSession(self.getReaderName())
  File "/home/john/Plocha/pySimReader-Serial-src-v2/pySIMserial.py", line 145, in openSession
    baudrate=9600)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 260, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 276, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I know there are tons of UnicodeDecodeError posts and I did try to figure it out, but I must be missing something.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    try:
    if (os.name == "posix"):
        s = "/dev/ttyUSB0\t"    
        #s = "/dev/cu.PL2303-3B1\t"
    if (os.name == "nt"):
        for i in range(1,10):
            s += "COM"+str(i)+"\t"
    except:
        print_exc()
    for i in s.split("\t"):
        if i:
            self.listbox.Append(i)

     ...

def getReaderName(self):
    return self.readerName

def connectReader(self):
    if not self.getReaderName():
        self.selectNewReader()
    if self.getReaderName():
        res = self.openSession(self.getReaderName())
        if res == 0:
            self.state = SIM_STATE_CONNECTED
            self.gatherInfo()

...

def openSession(self, portname):
    self.serialport = serial.Serial(port=portname,
                             parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
                             bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                             stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
                             timeout=1,
                             xonxoff=0,
                             rtscts=0,
                             baudrate=9600)
...

def selectNewReaderOK(self, *args):
    self.readerName = self.listbox.GetStringSelection()
    self.closeDialog()
```

Comment: Can you just tell, what is the result of type(self.listbox.GetStringSelection)

Comment: type(self.listbox.GetStringSelection) prints <type 'instancemethod'>